# com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb1: Name or service not known

Tags: linux, kubernetes

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb1: Name or service not known

how can I solve this problem in kubernetes yaml?

I described in my yaml file but it does not work.

```yaml
env:
  - name: MONGO_HOST
    value: mongodb1-service
  - name: MONGO_PORT
    value: "****"
```

I want to connect mongodb1-service with pod

Comment: your code does not get the value of MONGO_HOST variable.